# Laravel Livewire: Fetch data in FullCalendar jquery

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

In our application, we have activities module. I implemented the fullcalendar in our application but having a hard time to fetch data from my database

**Membership Dashboard View**

```
<div id="calendar">
</div>
<script>
   
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers:{
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
       });

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            events: '/full-calendar',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            
            // select:function(start, end, allday){
            //  var title = prompt('Event Title');

            //  if(title)
            //  {
            //      var start   = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'Y-MM-DD');
            //      var end     = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'Y-MM-DD');
                    
            //      $.ajax({
            //          url: "/full-calendar/action",
            //          type: "POST",
            //          data: {
            //              title: title,
            //              start: start,
            //              end: end
            //          },
            //          success:function(data){
            //              calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            //          }
            //      })
            //  }
            // }

        });

   });

</script>
```

EDITED

I followed the guide that gave by @Adyson, now I used the events as function but right now the URL is requesting infinite

**Membership Dashboard View**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            // events: '/members-dashboard/getCurrentMonthActivities',
            events: function(start,end){
                // var title    = prompt('Event Title');
                // var start    = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'Y-MM-DD');
                // var end  = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'Y-MM-DD');
                
                // $.ajax({
                //  url: "/members-dashboard/getCurrentMonthActivities",
                //  type: "POST",
                //  data: {
                //      // title: title,
                //      start: start,
                //      end: end
                //  },
                //  success:function(data){
                //      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                //  }
                // })
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            // select:function(start, end, allday){
            //  var title = prompt('Event Title');

            //  if(title)
            //  {
                    // var start    = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'Y-MM-DD');
                    // var end  = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'Y-MM-DD');
                    
                    // $.ajax({
                    //  url: "/full-calendar/action",
                    //  type: "POST",
                    //  data: {
                    //      title: title,
                    //      start: start,
                    //      end: end
                    //  },
                    //  success:function(data){
                    //      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    //  }
                    // })
            //  }
            // }

        });
```

Question: How do I fetch the data from my database?

Comment: The URL you give to fullCalendar's `events` option needs to point to a URL where fullCalendar can download event data in JSON format. It could point to a static JSON file, but more commonly it points to some server-side code which would retrieve the data from a data store (filtered by the dates fullCalendar supplies) and returns them encoded in the correct JSON array format. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: Alternatively you can specify a JS callback function as the source of the events - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function . That way if you need to do a different kind of request, or get the data from somewhere else in the client-side, or whatever, then you have full control to write JS code as needed to fetch the events. FullCalendar will then call the function whenever it needs to fetch event data.

Comment: Hello sir, I edited my post. Can you check why does it request infinite?

Comment: Here is the problem, I think: `success:function(data){
                //      calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                //  }`. You're telling it that, after it's fetched the events, it should fetch them again. "refetchEvents" will cause it to run the events function all over again. And of course that will complete the AJAX, and then run refetchEvents another time, and so on. What you actually need to do, as per the examples in the documentation, is pass the downloaded events data to your calendar via the provided callback.

Comment: So you're saying is, in my success:function, inside of it I should create a new function?

Comment: You don't create a function, you use the function fullcalendar gives you - look again at the example in the documentation

Comment: Is it possible to call another field? It just displayed the title, I want to display also the description

Comment: Yes but that's a separate question. You can use the eventRender callback to control the appearance of the event.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

In my controller I called the model then in my view, I created a new variable then passed the variable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:{
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        var activities = @json($activities);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            events: activities,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

        });

        function successResponse(data)
        {
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
    });
```